# JAXB required=true doesn't seem to require

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

We have this JAXB annotation:

```
 @XmlElement(name = "Strategy", required = true)
 protected List<Strategy> strategy;
```

If there are no `Strategy` elements present, no exception is thrown..  why is this?  Shouldn't we get an exception?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The JAXB reference implementation doesn't use this attribute for validation, it's purely there for documentation purposes.

If you need to validate the documents, you need to define an XML Schema, and inject it into the `Marshaller` or `Unmarshaller`, using `SchemaFactory`.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2696765/12604) for an example of loading the `Schema` from your `JAXBContext` to use in the `Marshaller`/`Unmarshaller`.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is purely for documenation - it's also used for schema generation. When you generate an XSD from your Java classes and you have `required = true` then the element declaration in the XSD will be generated with `minOccurs="1"`. You can then use the XSD for validating XML.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could use the `beforeMarshal` and `afterUnmarshal` methods to validate inputs as spec'd in [Marshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback) and [Unmarshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback).

The scheme under which these methods are accessed will also allow you to add an arbitrary `throws` clause to the method declaration. This means that when implementing these methods, you can safely use `javax.xml.bind.MarshalException` and `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException` *(or whatever sort of `Exception` you want)* to signal validation errors.