# JAXB-WS - Making a field mandatory using @WebMethod

Tags: jboss, annotations, jax-ws

I have a @WebMethod call

```
@WebMethod
public int cancelCampaign(String campaignId, String reason);
```

I'd like to make the campaignId field marked as mandatory. Not sure how to do that.

I'm using a JBOSS 7.1 server.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar requirement, and from SoapUI I noticed I was getting

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
     xmlns:bus="http://business.test.com/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <!-- optional -->
     <bus:addItem>
        <bus:item>
           <id>?</id>
           <!-- optional -->
           <name>?</name>
        </bus:item>
        <!-- optional -->
        <itemType>?</itemType>
     </bus:addItem>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

instead of

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
     xmlns:bus="http://business.test.com/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <bus:addItem>
        <bus:item>
           <id>?</id>
           <name>?</name>
        </bus:item>
        <itemType>?</itemType>
     </bus:addItem>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

A way out in JAX-WS Metro 2.0 RI is to annotate each parameter with

```
@XmlElement( required = true )
```

In my case, I had to do this to required WebMethod parameters and getters of all my required custom types, like so:

### In the WebService:

```
...
 @WebMethod( operationName = "getItems" )
   @WebResult( name = "item" )
   public List<Item> getItems(
     @WebParam( name = "itemType" ) @XmlElement( required = true ) String itemType );
...
```

### And in my POJO class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @XmlElement( required = true )
   private int               id;

   @XmlElement( required = true )
   private String            name;

   /**
    * Default constructor.
    */
   public Item() { }

   /**
    * @return the id
    *
    */       
   public int getId()
   {
      return id;
   }

   /* setter for id */

   /**
    * @return the name
    */
   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   /* setter for name */

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this with `JAX-WS` is to write some wrapper classes that specify the `required=true` flags on the `XmlElement` annotations. Your request element should look something like this:

```
@XmlType(name="YourRequestType", propOrder={"campaignId", "reason"})
public class YourRequest {
    @XmlElement(name="campaignId", required=true)
    private String campaignId;
    @XmlElement(name="reason", required=false)
    private String reason;

    //Getters and setters        

}
```

And your web method should look like this:

```
@WebMethod
public int cancelCampaign(@WebParam(name = "request") YourRequest request) {
   String campaignId = request.getCampaignId();

   return 0;
}
```

This will tell `JAXB` to generate `minOccurs=1` in your `XSD` for `campaignId` element.

Comment: For elements that I set to required=true, JAXB removes the minOccurs property. For required=false, the minOccurs remains present and is set to 0. Does a missing minOccurs property indicate that it is a required field?

Comment: Another thing that I found out about required=true in @XmlElement is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669632/jaxb-required-true-doesnt-seem-to-require

Comment: This approach results in an optional YourRequest element for me (albeit one with mandatory properties / types).