# Java web service code first set element as required

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'm building a code first web service in java and building it with maven. The web service itself works fine but I can't get rid of

> minOccurs="0"

in my generated wsdl:

```
<xs:complexType name="getHOP">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="getHopRequest" type="getHopRequest"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="getHOPResponse" type="getHOPResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="getHOPResponse">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="getHopResponse"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

My interface looks like this

```
@WebService
public interface GetHop {

GetHopResponse getHOP(
        @WebParam(name = "getHopRequest") GetHopRequest getHopRequest);
}
```

And this is my request class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getHopRequest", propOrder = { "companyId", "countryIsoCode",
    "currencyIsoCode", "paymentMethodId", "customerId", "totalAmount",
    "cartId", "successUrl", "failureUrl", "notifyUrl" })
public class GetHopRequest {

@XmlElement(required = true)
private String companyId;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String countryIsoCode;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String currencyIsoCode;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String paymentMethodId;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String customerId;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String totalAmount;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String cartId;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String successUrl;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String failureUrl;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String notifyUrl;

// Getter and setter here

}
```

Already was able to set all elements in the getHopRequest as required by

> @XmlElement(required = true)

But I can't figure out how to do this for the request/response itself.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

*This has not be verified nor tested.*

You can add the `@XmlElement` on your Web Service Parameter of your Web method and set `required=true`, as follows:

```
@WebService
public interface GetHop {

GetHopResponse getHOP(
        @WebParam(name = "getHopRequest") @XmlElement(required=true) GetHopRequest getHopRequest);
}
```

- [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642335/jaxb-ws-making-a-field-mandatory-using-webmethod).

Comment: Also, reposting another answer isn't really correct behavior. A link in the comments would be better, or, if you think the questions are too similar, a duplicate vote.

Comment: @Keppil I answered the question first then looked for a similar answer on Google. Besides, none of the questions found on SO were accepted to vote as a duplicate.

Comment: In that case removing this answer when you found an almost identical one would make sense, right?

Comment: well the answer summarizes it a little bit to that what I really needed and it doesn't hurt anyone - unfortunately it also doesn't work ^^

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types and not primitive types may have `null` values in the marshalled objects. By default they are not required and `minOccurs="0"` indicate that they may not exist at all.

If you need to remove `minOccurs="0"` then you should use:

`@XmlElement(nillable=false, required=true)`

After that the generated WSDL will not include `minOccurs`, because `minOccurs` has the default value `1` and it's ignored.

Comment: Added this in my interface and also tried it in the service but still doesn't work :/ only works fine for all those String types as you can see above but not for the whole request itself