# JAXB Marshal missing Attribute/Element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have the following JAXB object:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "AuthEntry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuthEntry {

    @XmlElement(name = "Account")
    private Account account;

    @XmlElement(name = "Key", required = true)
    private String key;

    @XmlElement(name = "Expire", required = true)
    private Date expire;

    // Getter & Setter
    // ...
```

I use the JAXB `Marshaller` to convert the object to XML:

```
public static <T> String marshalObject(T pObject) throws JAXBException, IOException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(pObject.getClass());

    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        m.marshal(pObject, stream);
        stream.flush();

        return new String(stream.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

It runs smoothly without any exception, however, the result is always missing the Element `Key`. I tried to change it to Attribute instead, but it doesn't work too. Here is an example output:

```
<AuthEntry xmlns:ns2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet3">
    <Account ID="1" Username="datvm" Password="datvm" FullName="NullPtrExc" Active="true"/>
    <Expire>2014-06-06T20:07:32.428+07:00</Expire>
</AuthEntry>
```

I have tried to change the `Key` name to another, such as `AuthKey`, but it is still missing. What did I do wrong?

**EDIT** I found the problem, it is because my `Key` value is `null`. If it contains value, then it is written to the XML. However, can you please explain why in the XMLElement, I wrote `required = true`, yet it still missing when it is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JAXB & `null`

By default a JAXB implementation will not marshal an attribute or element for a `null` value.  You can have JAXB generate an element that contains the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute using the following:

```
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
```

### Empty Elements

An empty element is not a valid representation for null.  For example if your element was of type `xs:dateTime` and the corresponding element was empty, then that document would not validate against the XML schema.

Answer (score 2):

JAXB ignores the `required` attribute, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669632/jaxb-required-true-doesnt-seem-to-require).

However, if you create a XSD schema from your classes using `schemagen`, the `required` attribute of the annotation is honored and the XML element will be required according to the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same problem with field missing when marshaled. The field was not `null` (originally).
When debugged I find that in `jaxbContext.typeMap.myFieldParrentClass.value.properties.singleElementLeafPropertyForMyField.hiddenByOverride = true`.
I had parent class and child classes. Field was both in parent and child classes and correct value from parent would be overwritten by `null` from child class field.