# Handling invalid enum values while doing JAXB Unmarshalling

Tags: web-services, soapui, jaxb2

My Jaxb has created a Enum class based on the XML schema set up.

```
**enum Fruit {
    APPLE,ORANGE;
}**
```

I am using a SOAP UI to check my web service. Since it is a free form entry, if i give a wrong fruit say **"Guva"** then instead of throwing an exception it is returning it as null after doing the UnMarshalling.

How can i avoid this? Should i use custom enum class instead of JAXB generated one. Please give some example. i.e.

regards
sri

Answer (score 22):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

By default your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will not fail on any conversion exceptions.  If you are using the JAXB APIs to do the unmarshalling then you can set a `ValidationEventHandler` to catch any problems.  Below is an example.

**Root**

```
package forum12147306;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private int number;
    private Fruit fruit;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Fruit getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

    public void setFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }

}
```

**Fruit**

```
package forum12147306;

public enum Fruit {

    APPLE, 
    ORANGE;

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum12147306;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    private static final String XML = "<root><number>ABC</number><fruit>Guva</fruit></root>";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

            @Override
            public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent validationEvent) {
                 System.out.println(validationEvent.getMessage());
                 //validationEvent.getLinkedException().printStackTrace();
                 return true;
            }

        });

        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(XML));
    }

}
```

---

**JAXB REFERENCE IMPLEMENTATION**

Unfortunately there appears to be a bug in the JAXB RI as a validation event is not being through for the invalid enum value.

```
Not a number: ABC
```

**Work Around**

Write your own `XmlAdapter` to handle to conversion to/from the `Fruit` enum:

***FruitAdapter***

```
package forum12147306;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class FruitAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Fruit> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(Fruit fruit) throws Exception {
        return fruit.name();
    }

    @Override
    public Fruit unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        try {
            return Fruit.valueOf(string);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new JAXBException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**Fruit**

Use the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation to associate the `XmlAdapter` with the `Fruit` enumb.

```
package forum12147306;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FruitAdapter.class)
public enum Fruit {

    APPLE, 
    ORANGE;

}
```

**New Output**

```
Not a number: ABC
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class forum12147306.Fruit.Guva]
```

---

**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

Using MOXy both validation events are thrown.  To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html.

```
Exception Description: The object [ABC], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[number-->number/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(forum12147306.Root --> [DatabaseTable(root)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ABC"

Exception Description: No conversion value provided for the value [Guva] in field [fruit/text()].
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[fruit-->fruit/text()]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(forum12147306.Root --> [DatabaseTable(root)])
```

Comment: thanks, very much for the detailed example. "...there appears to be a bug in the JAXB" - This behaviour still exists. Maybe mismatching enums are not critical errors :-) Your 'workaround' works fine. I am using this design for non-enums as well. Really great!

Comment: Blaise Doughan, had anything changed in MOXy since you posted this answer? I can't seem to get MOXy 2.6.2 to fire up events on unknown enum values in XML or Json. Do I have to use XmlJavaTypeAdapter with MOXy too?

Comment: And the bug still exists in JAXB! Thanks

Comment: How can I use this solution with Spring, using only annotations?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer based on original reply. You need to do 2 things

1. implement custom adapter to raise and exception
2. add event handler to fail unmarshalling

**Fruit.java** defines and uses the adapter

```
package forum12147306;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FruitAdapter.class)
public enum Fruit {

    APPLE, 
    ORANGE;

}

class FruitAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Fruit> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(Fruit fruit) throws Exception {
        return fruit.name();
    }

    @Override
    public Fruit unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        try {
            return Fruit.valueOf(string);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new JAXBException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The event handler for unmarshaller that fails parsing on error - i.e it returns **false** (you might need to decide when to fail and when not to fail)

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent validationEvent) {
             return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative consists in generating XSD schemas as presented in here: [how can i unmarshall in jaxb and enjoy the schema validation without using an explicit schema file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603778/how-can-i-unmarshall-in-jaxb-and-enjoy-the-schema-validation-without-using-an-ex).

Here is the snippet I stole from [dolbysurnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654200/dolbysurnd):

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

private static List<DOMResult> generateJaxbSchemas(JAXBContext context) throws IOException {
    final List<DOMResult> domResultList = new ArrayList<>();
    context.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {
        @Override
        public Result createOutput(String ns, String file) throws IOException {
            DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
            domResult.setSystemId(file);
            domResultList.add(domResult);
            return domResult;
        }
    });
    return domResultList;
}

private static Unmarshaller createUnmarshaller(JAXBContext context) throws SAXException, IOException, JAXBException {
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    List<DOMSource> domSourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DOMResult domResult : generateJaxbSchemas(context)) {
        domSourceList.add(new DOMSource(domResult.getNode()));
    }
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(domSourceList.toArray(new DOMSource[0]));
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    return unmarshaller;
}

public void unmarshal(JAXBContext context, Reader reader) throws JAXBException, SAXException, IOException {
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = createUnmarshaller(context);
    Object result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
}
```